# Windows 8: Wait until setup tasks complete before tearing down extended splash screen

Tags: javascript, windows-8, splash-screen

I am currently trying to add an extended splash screen to my app that automatically removes itself once it has completed downloading an RSS feed and has found valid high resolution images in that feed to make thumbnails out of (On the first launch of the app, this can take 5+ seconds, leaving the user with a blank screen).

Unfortunately, the MSDN Extended Splash Screen example has not been rather helpful since they dismiss theirs via pressing a button rather than waiting for various nested functions to complete. Other examples I've found skip over important details that is not helpful to someone who is relatively new to app programming.

```
app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            // your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            // Restore application state here.
        }

        performSetupTasks();
        // Retrieve splash screen object.
        var splash = args.detail.splashScreen;
        // Display the extended splash screen.
        displayExtendedSplash(splash);

        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(removeExtendedSplash()));            
    }
};
```

Instead, the above code immediately removes the extended splash screen; do I need to add anything to the code that reports back `performSetupTasks()` is not complete?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. I used a placeholder window.setTimeout (or something like that) and have since abandoned the project. It was months ago, I'd have to look up the source code when I arrive back home from work). But it does not work as I would like, and using a window.timeOut method in a splash screen yields unpredictable and inconsistent results and can fail certification. Someday, I'd like to revisit the project, since I have much more experience now, and probably rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up following this tutorial and it seems to work just fine for me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/21/creating-a-fast-and-fluid-app-launch-experience.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're probably doing async operation in your `performSetupTasks();` method.

Refactor your code to return that promise, so the splashscreen will be removed only after that promise is fulfilled:

```
function removeExtendedSplash() {
    var promise = WinJS.xhr(...);
    promise.then(function(result) { ... });
    return promise;
}
```

`args.setPromise(removeExtendedSplash());`

You can also try this extended splash screen implementation: https://gist.github.com/petertakacs/5330117

Comment: Yes, I already knew of the promise approach (Microsoft has it littered all over their site that they want you to use an async-promise system). I was having trouble implementing it at the time with my particular project (despite putting in promises, the splash screen would dismiss immediately, which I'm sure was my fault), but I have abandoned it for quite some time now. Nevertheless, I am going to +1 your post, because this is important information for others to see as building your app with the WinJS.Promise object in mind is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Script to pause the splash screen display before moving into the application…

1.) After  " app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) { " in  default.js add below code

```
    pauseDisplayOfSplashScreen(2500);
```

2.)Above app.oncheckpoint = function (args),add following function.

```
    function pauseDisplayOfSplashScreen(milliseconds) {
    milliseconds += new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date() < milliseconds) { }
}
```

For your clear understanding here is the full splash screen pause working default.js:

```
   // For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
   // http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509
  (function () {
    "use strict";

     WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

      var app = WinJS.Application;
      var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {

        //pause for two seconds
        pauseDisplayOfSplashScreen(2500);

        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !==   activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            // your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            // Restore application state here.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
};


function pauseDisplayOfSplashScreen(milliseconds) {
    milliseconds += new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date() < milliseconds) { }
}
app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
    // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
    // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
    // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
    // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
    // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
    // args.setPromise().


};

app.start();

 })();
```

Hope this will solve your problem :)

Comment: This does not answer my question. I do not want to pause the default splash screen, I want to dismiss a custom extended splash screen that I have created, which shows the user loading information and a progress bar, and self-dismisses after all loading is complete in order to show the landing page.